# Что не так с ASP.NET Identity в Onion архитектуре?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Решил, что для меня настало время пробовать крутые вещи, как Onion архитектура Repository+UnitOfWork, но мне довольно сильно понравилась ASP.NET Identity, которую я бы хотел совместить с такой архитектурой приложения. Примеры, которые нашлись в сети мне не очень понравились. К примеру, http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.10.php тут полностью нарушена архитектура слоёв, а именно:

-в BLL слой подключен EntityFramework + Identity.EntityFramework
-в DAL слое наблюдается куча бизнес логики в виде ApplicationRoleManager и ApplicationUserManager

и тд...

Поэтому было решено сделать свой велосипед. Для начала я взял за пример проект, который генерируется при создании ASP.NET MVC с уже включенной Identity и решил повторить его функционал, при этом разнеся на 3 слоя.
Вот что вышло:
https://github.com/dmitrievMV/OnionArchitectureWithASPNETIdentity

В DAL:

- Сущности.
- Контекст EF
- Repository+UnitOfWork
- UserStore

Все реализации в сборке закрыты, кроме UnitOfWork и UserStore. UserStore принимает в конструктор UOW и работает с репозиториями. Наружу смотрят только интерфейсы. Структура БД полностью повторяет пример от мелкомягких, кроме того, что основные ключи int.

В BLL:
-ApplicationUserManager

В WEB
-ApplicationSignInManager

Собственно, помогите пожалуйста, потратьте немного времени, просто проинспектируйте код. Ответьте на пару вопросов:

- Правильно ли я реализовал Repository + UnitOfWork
- Правильно ли реализовано Dispose
- В каком слое, по вашему должен находится ApplicationSignInManager, ведь он использует OWIN и работает с ApplicationUserManager
- Ввиду того, что о базе и ORM не знает ни один слой, кроме DAL, я решил вынести connectionString в константу, это нормальный подход?
- Есть смысл вынести сущности в отдельный проект и отделить их от аннотаций для бд?
- В примере в owin контекст засовывают ef контекст вот таким образом: app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create); насколько это оправдано и стоит ли так делать?
- В реализации UserStore для EF очень странно ведут себя с dispose и у меня ощущения, что некоторые данные висят в памяти постоянно, так ли это?
- Насколько вообще оправдан такой велосипед?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом ваш вариант рабочий. Но если хочется получить более качественный код я бы порекомендовал следующее:

1. Отказаться от использования `OwinContext` напрямую, убрать весь код использующий его. Вместо этого использовать любой менеджер DI: `Autofac`, `Ninject`, `Unity` и пр. Я выбрал `Autofac` из-за отличной документации. В таком случае не понадобится тащить OWIN в другие слои приложения, а получать зависимости будет очень просто указывая параметры в конструкторе. В `OwinContext` для этого нужно использовать анти-паттерн Service Locator:

   ```
   var manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
   ```
2. В `UnitOfWork` у вас много лишнего. В идеале он не должен сам создавать контекст/подключение, а должен получать его из DI контейнера в конструкторе. И он не должен реализовывать `IDisposable`. Контроль за контекстом лучше доверить менеджеру DI. В `Autofac` мой конфиг для DAL с nhibernate:

   ```
   builder.Register<ISessionFactory>(c => SessionFactory.Create()).SingleInstance();
   builder.Register<IStatelessSession>(c => c.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenStatelessSession()).InstancePerRequest();
   builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
   builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerRequest();
   ```

   Здесь я сначала регистрирую синглтон фабрики сессий. А потом с помощью нее новый объект `IStatelessSession` аналог `DbContext` на каждый запрос. В конце запроса менеджер DI сам его завершит. И в таком случае `IDisposable` не нужен. Здесь же я регистрирую в контейнер свою реализацию `IUnitOfWork` и generic-репозитория `IRepository<>`. Сам `IUnitOfWork` должен только управлять транзакцией: стартовать, откатывать, фиксировать не более.
3. Я оставил ApplicationUserManager в самом проекте Web Api из-за зависимости от OWIN. Но всю логику работы с базой перенес в свой сервис для работы с пользователям Asp Identity - `IdentityUserService`. Конфиг `Autofac` для ASP Identity:

   ```
   builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserStore>().As<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().InstancePerRequest();
   builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
   builder.Register<IDataProtectionProvider>(c => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()).InstancePerRequest();
   builder.Register<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>(c => new ApplicationOAuthProvider(Startup.PublicClientId)).SingleInstance();
   ```
4. `connectionString` лучше вынести в Web.Config
5. Сущности и интерфейсы лучше выносить в отдельные проекты. Это позволит использовать одни и те же модели во всех слоях приложения. Не придется поддерживать отдельно иерархию моделей в DAL, в BOL и в WebApi/View-слое. На сайте http://metanit.com есть раздел про более удачную Onion-архитектуру. Там используется такой подход.
6. Данные в EF будут висеть если разделять один и тот же контекст к базе между всеми запросами. Хорошей практикой считается создавать новый контекст на каждый запрос. Так же можно отключить отслеживание объектов с помощью `AsNoTracking()` и ускорить EF.
7. Я использую generic-репозитории и generic-сервисы, так как это избавляет от тонны шаблонного кода. Так как я использую одну иерархию моделей во всех слоях у меня не нарушается инкапсуляция при использовании IQueryable в бизнес-логике. В том что IQueryable используется в бизнес слое нет ничего плохого, так как это базовый класс .Net по сути представляющий собой паттерн Builder или Query Object. Он дает больше гибкости, так как запросы можно строить динамически в бизнес слое и не перегружать репозиторий кучей похожих методов. Так же он уменьшает шаблонный код, так как можно написать один базовый запрос, а затем подставлять в него разные предикаты и проекции - иными словами по максимуму использовать ФП.

Comment: `builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>))` - как вы при таком подходе будете делать конкретные реализации репозиториев?

Comment: По пункту 5 - если сущности и интерфейсы вынести в отдельный проект или отдельные проекты - получится уже не луковичная, а многогранная архитектура. Кстати, она и правда проще в поддержке, хоть и выглядит сложнее.

Comment: Использование IQueryable заставляет модель хранения полностью повторять модель бизнес-логики - нет возможности что-то кардинально изменить в DAL. Например, добавить глубокую версионность по всем сущностям. Или динамическое отслеживание зависимостей.

Comment: Если зарегистрировать generic для конкретной сущности он будет иметь приоритет на обобщенным generic. Например чтобы для модели IdentityUser объявить кастомный репозиторий нужно сделать так: `builder.RegisterType<MyCustomIdentityRepository>().As<IRepository<IdentityUser>>().InstancePerRequest();`

Comment: В луковичной ведь так же создается отдельный Class Library для сущностей и для доменных интерфейсов - две эти библиотеки образуют Domain. В целом да получается очень похоже на многогранную. Основной плюс что не надо делать несколько вариаций модели: UserEntity, UserBO, UserDTO и пр. так как Domain библиотеки можно подключить к любому вышестоящему слою.

Comment: Использование доменной сущности в качестве хранимой - это возможность, а не требование. У вас всегда должен быть способ создать отдельную сущность. При использовании же IQueryable это выльется в написание своего провайдера.

Comment: IQueryable используется только в связке с Linq для SELECT-запросов. А все Update, Insert, Delete делаются либо стандартными средствами ORM, либо с помощью паттерна QueryObject. Т.е фактически в предложенном мною варианте делается один generic-репозиторий:

Comment: И итоге вы теряете всю абстракцию слоя хранения. Вы не можете менять схему хранения без изменения бизнес-логики.

Comment: Если нужно разделять модель хранения и бизнес модель, то я согласен IQueryable не получится использовать. Но с другой стороны настолько ли важна эта строгость, можно бизнес модель сделать с оглядкой на базу. Я не сторонник строгих подходов из DDD, которые замедляют разработку.

Comment: У вас интересный холивар. Но подскажите по первому пункту каким образом вынести ApplicationUserManager в di если он принимает IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options который потом используется var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User, int>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }

Comment: а ApplicationSignInManager использует IOwinContext.Authentication

Comment: Можете сделать как в этой статье https://developingsoftware.com/configuring-autofac-to-work-with-the-aspnet-identity-framework-in-mvc-5/. Или погуглить еще варианты, на stack есть уже такие вопросы.

Comment: Супер. Теперь понял. Есть тупой вопрос. У меня есть статик класс со статик методом. К примеру отправка имейла, я хочу обернуть отправку имейла в try catch и в catch записать ошибку в базу. проблема в том что этот статик класс в bl а для записи в базу везде создается uow + repository через autofac. я уже себе моск сломал как такое сделать

Comment: Если это в web слое я могу сделать DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();

Comment: Вам нужно сделать обычный класс сервис для отправки писем EmailSendingService, зарегистрировать его как SingleInstance(). Статику не используйте с Autofac. Зависимости не правильно получать через  DependencyResolver, нужно просто создать конструктор с нужными зависимостями, как здесь http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/21.4.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Зачем вы настолько часто используете full dispose pattern? Ваши классы никогда не будут владеть неуправляемыми ресурсами - значит, финализаторы им не нужны в принципе!
2. Зачем UserStore закрывает Unit of Work? Не надо закрывать то, чего не создавал!
3. Зачем в контроллере сделано два альтернативных способа получения зависимостей? Очевидно же, что будет использоваться только один из них.
4. Чем вам не угодил стандартный UserStore?
5. Generic Repository - антипаттерн. Он ничего не упрощает! Метод `IQueryable<TObject> Get()` раскрывает всю инкапсуляцию. В итоге, у вас логика работы с БД будет "размазана" по слою бизнес-логики.

   Надо либо отказаться от отдельного слоя DAL (точнее, признать, что библиотека EF сама по себе является неплохим слоем DAL) - либо отказаться от "обобщенных" репозиториев и реализовывать логику построения запросов в том слое, который для этого и предназначен.
6. Почему Connection string не в конфиге?!
7. Что класс ApplicationSignInManager делает в App_Start?!

Comment: 1. Dispose для rolestore и userstore выполены по аналогии rolestore и userstore из identity.entityframework библиотеки
2. Потому что так же реализовано в identity.entityframework
3. Контроллеры практически без изменений взяты из стартового проекта 
4. Тем что он привязан к своей реализации сущностей в entityframework. Цель DAL слоя создание абстракции над орм/бд.
5. У меня не хватает опыта в этом вопросе
6. Уже в конфиге, осознал ошибку.
7. Он там находится потому что использует Owin и я не решился вынести его в BLL слой. Это есть один из вопросов.

Comment: 4. Ваш собственный UserStore точно так же привязан к EF.

Comment: он использует uow который должен скрыть ef. просто как вы верно подметили моя реализация репозитория несколько предпологает возможность работы с данными с помощью IQueryable

Comment: @PavelMayorov, почему GenericRepositiry анти-паттерн?